# Работа с большим кодом

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Уважаемые господа, прошу вас поделитесь опытом.

Многие php-разработчики наверняка сталкивались с задачей быстрого изучения php приложения написанного другими программистами.(Самописные проекты, framework-и, cms, и прочие плохо задокументированные приложения). Если этот код небольшой, то все сводится к простому изучению кода от входного скрипта index.php и прослеживание всех веток приложения до конца. Таким образом в голове возникает очень чёткая картина работы кода.

Но вот если это сложный, очень большой php-код , скажем 300-500 тыс. а то и млн. строк. Логику работы которого , по-настоящему целиком держать в голове одновременно, не по силам даже мастеру Йода. Возникают определённые сложности.

Мой вопрос сводится к поиску дебаггера, (код-реверсёра?) с возможностью рисования схемы работы приложения целиком, списком всех классов, методов, функций и ветки их связей. Входных и выходных данных, скорости работы, запросов к базе ну и т.д.

И вообще какие есть методы работы с неизвестным кодом, кроме разборки в ручную?

Comment: Зачем держать миллионы строк или классов в голове? достаточно посмотреть и изучить ядро системы, из чего выстраиваются и вырастают другие классы. А также большая система наверняка построена из отдельных модулей, которые также выросли из ядра. Соответственно подчиняются практический одной логике и более того, с большинством модулей можешь в процессе работы вообще не столкнуться и не работать. Зачем их все запоминать и выстраивать их список?

Comment: Если вам не трудно, можете более детально описать этот процесс?